# Google Cloud Endpoints list of entities as response

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I'm trying to send a list (Collection) of Google App Engine entities as a response to an API request, but some of my entities have a parent key (using objectify) that doesn't show up in the response. Does anyone know how to change this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Please provide part of the code where the issue is happening and input/output you are expecting.